# I keep getting 405 Method Not Allowed on a simple GET Request in WebApi 2.2

Tags: controller, asp.net-web-api2

I keep getting 405 Method Not Allowed on a simple GET Request in WebApi 2.2

I start off with an Empty Web Application Project, then check add folders and core references for WebApi.

I make no alterations to the defaults here:

```
Protected Sub Application_Start()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
End Sub

Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services

    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

My controller class is like so:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Net.Http

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class TokensController
        Inherits ApiController

        Private Const TOKEN_LENGTH As Integer = 8
        Private Const TOKEN_MIN As Integer = CInt(10 ^ (TOKEN_LENGTH - 1))
        Private Const TOKEN_MAX As Integer = CInt(10 ^ TOKEN_LENGTH - 1)
        Private rnd As New Random

        Private Shared _tokens As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Token)

        Public Function Post(tok As Token) As HttpResponseMessage
            If tok IsNot Nothing Then
                tok.TokenCode = rnd.Next(TOKEN_MIN, TOKEN_MAX)
                tok.DateCreated = Now

                _tokens.Add(tok.TokenCode, tok)

                Dim resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)

                resp.Headers.Location = New Uri(Me.Request.RequestUri, "Tokens/" & tok.TokenCode)

                Return resp
            Else
                Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If

        End Function

        Public Function [Get](tokenCode As Integer) As Integer
            Return tokenCode
        End Function


        'Public Function [Get](tokenCode As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
        '    If _tokens.ContainsKey(tokenCode) Then
        '        Dim tok = _tokens(tokenCode)

        '        Return Ok(Of Token)(tok)
        '    Else
        '        Return NotFound()
        '    End If
        'End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

From Fiddler - 
Request:

```
GET http://localhost:13850/api/Tokens/36067467 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:13850
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcUHJvamVjdHNcRm91bmRhdGlvblxUZXN0QXBpXGFwaVxUb2tlbnNcMzYwNjc0Njc=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 17 Aug 2014 09:56:16 GMT
Content-Length: 72

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

I've been stuck on this for hours, any help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, Such a simple solution:

```
 Public Function GetToken(**tokenCode** As Integer) As IHttpActionResult

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name:="DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{**tokenCode**}",
    defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
```

the param name in the controller method must match the param in your routeTemplate definition.